# Simulate throwing an exception for mocked domain class

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, mocking

I am in the process of writing [unit tests](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/9.%20Testing.html#9.1%20Unit%20Testing) for a Grails service class. The service class uses multiple domain classes. Creating mocks for the domain classes works like a charm using the `mockDomain` method. Even the code paths that test if a domain object can be saved correctly (domain validation) can be written easily. However, in my code I also wrapped domain object operations with a `try/catch` block that handles the exception cases. Is there a way to simulate that a domain operation throws an exception? This can easily be done with Mock frameworks like [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) (`thenThrow`) or [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/) (`andThrow`) but I am primarily looking for a way native to Grails. I'd be open to frameworks that complement the Grails testing framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple using Groovy's metaclassing. For this example, I'll say one of your domain classes is Foo.

```
void testFooThrowsException(){
    def fooInstance = new Foo()
    fooInstance.metaClass.methodToTest = {arg1, arg2->
        throw new CustomException("I'm an exception")
    }

    shouldFail CustomException, {fooInstance.methodToTest("val1", "val2")}
}
```

Once you've modified the metaclass of an instance, that instance will have the modified behavior for it's full lifecycle. [Read more on metaclassing on the Groovy site.](http://groovy.codehaus.org/ExpandoMetaClass) It's one of the coolest parts of Groovy, IMO.